# How to export dataframe column wise to separate csv files? And how to append the columns from different dataframe to the separated csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

`df1` is this:

```
    accel_name numb frequency resistance phase
idx                                           
3            K    0       -33          1  4030
4            K    1       -16          2  4028
5            K    2       -18         12  4036
6            K    3       -14         -3  4054
12           K    4        -2         17  4048
13           K    5       -18         12  4048
```

`df2` is this:

```
    accel_name numb frequency resistance phase
idx                                           
7            P    0      -452       4089   329
8            P    1      -428       4082   427
9            P    2      -382       4078   518
10           P    3      -363       4052   545
11           P    4      -347       4064   508
14           P    5      -373       4068   409
```

output :

1. append df2 columns to df1
2. output frequency.csv, resistance.csv, phase.csv

Comment: what you want is ambiguous, please provide the expected output for at least one of the files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `df.to_csv()` to export the relevant dataframes

```
import os
import pandas as pd

filepath = os.getcwd()
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).sort_index()
cols = ['frequency', 'resistance', 'phase']
for col in cols:
    df[[col]].to_csv(filepath + '\\' + col + '.csv')

print(df)
    accel_name numb frequency resistance phase
idx                                           
3            K    0       -33          1  4030
4            K    1       -16          2  4028
5            K    2       -18         12  4036
6            K    3       -14         -3  4054
7            P    0      -452       4089   329
8            P    1      -428       4082   427
9            P    2      -382       4078   518
10           P    3      -363       4052   545
11           P    4      -347       4064   508
12           K    4        -2         17  4048
13           K    5       -18         12  4048
14           P    5      -373       4068   409
```

Output: frequency.csv, phase.csv, resistance.csv

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you that helps. But I am trying to save to the specific folder which contains freqency.csv, resistance.csv, and phase.csv files. How to provide file path to the that folder ?

Comment: I've updated my code, so you can `print(filepath)` to see what you get and modify to the new location from there

Answer (score 2):

`df.to_csv` is the simple way to export pandas Dataframes to csvs.
To combine the columns, I have first extracted them into `phase` and `phase2` dataframes, and then used `pd.concat` to combine (concatenate) them. Note that this is probably not the fastest way to do this, but it is an easy to understand set of steps.

```py
import pandas as pd
phase = df1['phase']
phase2 = df2['phase']
phases = pd.concat([phase, phase2])
phasees.to_csv('phase_data.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, use a loop on the concatenated dataframes, slice columns using set operations:

```
cols = {'frequency', 'resistance', 'phase'}
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
for c in cols:
    df.drop(columns=cols.difference([c])).to_csv(f'{c}.csv')
```

example, `frequency.csv`:

```
,accel_name,numb,frequency
3,K,0,-33
4,K,1,-16
5,K,2,-18
6,K,3,-14
12,K,4,-2
13,K,5,-18
7,P,0,-452
8,P,1,-428
9,P,2,-382
10,P,3,-363
11,P,4,-347
14,P,5,-373
```